# Plane wave conditions

Tags: optics, wavefunction, plane-wave

Which conditions have to be fulfilled in order to approximate a light beam by a plane
wave (i.e. $\phi(x)\approx \phi(0)e^{ikx}$)?

I am looking for both mathematical and experimental conditions. At the moment, the only thing I can think of is to consider that the source is at a very distant point and the use of collimators.